# Oreo Background Service Issue

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

Please  I need a  quick look into this.
For classes that extends Service directly not IntentService, How do you start such services??
I have just been seeing extension of IntentService which doesn't suit my case study. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the first paragraph of the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service):

> Services can be started with Context.startService() and Context.bindService().

Also check out [services overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), it has nice explanations and examples, e.g.:

1. Create a service by extending Service class:

   public class HelloService extends Service {
       ...
   }
2. Start a service:

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
   startService(intent);

Comment: The only answer that actually addresses OP's question, short and precise, +1.